javafx getHostServices().showDocuments() brings up chrome instead of default browser (Linux)
I'm trying to display a html document from a JavaFX app.  So I called
getHostServices().showDocument(filename);
But instead of showing the document in the default browser Firefox, the system brings up Chrome and displays the file in it.  Chrome even prompt "Google Chrome isn't your default browser" and shows a big button to "Set as default".
How can I make sure the document is showing in the default browser?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox 125.0, Chrome 124.0.6367.60, openjdk 11.0.22, javafx-sdk-11.0.2 (from gluon)

It appears the implementation simply returns the first browser b in a hard-coded list for which executing "which "+b has non-empty return. You could reasonably easily reimplement that directly for platforms that aren't windows or mac, though it's a bit of an unsatisfactory solution. What does executing xdg-open url from the command line (replacing url with the actual url you are opening) do?

@James_D Thanks for the info.  xdg-open brings up firefox.

I looked at the code.  The list of browsers starts with xdg-open.  Why didn't it bring up Firefox?  Strange.

This code does bring up the default browser, Firefox:       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"xdg-open", filename});

Possibly the app is running under a different user, or with a different path variable (or perhaps some other environment variable) set? I don't know though, I am just guessing at this point. What you're describing is hard to explain.

I figured it out.  The source you pointed to was a newer version.  I'm running on jfx 11.0.2.  In that source, the browsers list does not have xdg-open.  It is just {"google-chrome", "firefox", "opera",  "konqueror", "mozilla"}

You can post an answer to your own question

According to the source code, the behavior of HostServices.showDocument() on Linux is simply going through a list of commands to open the url argument.  With the version javafx-sdk-11.0.2 (downloaded from gluonhq), the list is {"google-chrome", "firefox", "opera", "konqueror", "mozilla"}, therefore, google chrome gets to open the file no matter which browser is the default on Linux.
On a later version of javafx (pointed out by James_D), the command "xdg-open" is added as the first element of the list. This should lead to the expected behavior of the showDocument method.  Although I have yet to test it.
